# Button in custom cell and reloading parent tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have *tableViewController* and RSS feeds loaded in the *tableView*. I want to implement "header like" cell (of type *OrderCell.h/.m*) with "order by date" and "order by popularity" custom buttons that reorder *rssItems* array and refresh the table view when pressed.

How can I refresh the *tableView* from *OrderCell* object method? I have no problem reordering the rssItems array because I defined it as a static var with static methods available from outside the class *TableViewController*.
My problem is calling *[xxx.tableView reloadData];* when a user clicks a button "order by".
Since OrderCell object is instantiated from TableViewController object how can I call the reload method of TableViewController object?

Thanks in advance,
Luka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own protocol which will be implemented (Confirmed) by the `TableViewController` class ,

**In myTableClass.h**

```
@protocol AppDelegate

-(void) OrderSelected ;

@end

@interface myTableClass : UITableViewController <AppDelegate> 
{
  .......
}
@end
```

**In OrderCell.h**

```
@interface OrderCell : .....
{
  id<AppDelegate> myDelegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)  id<AppDelegate> myDelegate;;
@end
```

**In OrderCell.cpp**

```
@synthesize myDelegate;

-(void) myButtonAction:(id) sender
{
   [myDelegate OrderSelected]; 
}
```

and

**In myTableClass.cpp**

When you create the OrderCell just write the Online Statement

```
myOrderCell.myDelegate = self;
```

and implement the protocol function

```
-(void) OrderSelected 
 {
   [self.tableView reloadTable];
 }
```

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM ! Thank you and thanks to Delgate pattern :) 
Luka

Answer (score 0):

add delegate in you other class for you table view controller first and assign your current tableview controller to that delegate and in your table view controller add a method like

```
 -(void) updateTableItems {
    [self.table reloadData];
}


-(void) threadLoop { 

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTableItems) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}
```

now using delegate of other class call threadLoop of your table view controller,
good luck